# zipWithUniqueId() in flambo using clojure

Tags: clojure, apache-spark, flambo

I want to create a rdd such that each row has an index. I tried the following

Given an rdd:

```
["a" "b" "c"] 

(defn make-row-index [input]
  (let [{:keys [col]} input]
    (swap! @rdd assoc :rdd (-> (:rdd xctx)
                          (f/map #(vector %1 %2 ) (range))))))
```

Desired output:

```
 (["a" 0] ["b" 1] ["c" 2])
```

I got an arity error, since f/map is used  as `(f/map rdd fn)` 
Wanted to use `zipWithUniqueId()` in apache spark but I'm lost on how to implement this and I cant find equivalent function in flambo. Any suggestion and help is appreciated.

[Apache-spark zip with Index](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.zipWithIndex)

[Map implementation in flambo](http://yieldbot.github.io/flambo/codox/flambo.api.html#var-map)

Thanks

Comment: @zero323 Kindly help me with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `zipWithIndex` followed by `map` using `untuple`:

```
(def rdd (f/parallelize sc ["a" "b" "c"]))
(f/map (.zipWithIndex rdd) f/untuple)
```

You can use `.zipWithUniqueId` exactly the same way but result will be different from what you expect. `zipWithUniqueId` will generate pairs but index field won't be ordered.

It should be also possible to use `zip` with, but as far as I can tell it doesn't work with infinite range.

```
(def idx (f/parallelize sc (range (f/count rdd))))
(f/map (.zip rdd idx) f/untuple)
```

Whenever you use `zip` you should be careful though Generally speaking RDD should be considered as an unordered collection if there is a shuffling involved.

Comment: I also have another block - I tried this

 `(defn catch-specific-rows
  "Function to catch the row(s) with the specific Row Number(s) in rows-list
  input = { :rows-list [ val(s)]}"
  [row input]
  (let [{:keys [ rows-list ]} input
        row-and-index (->(:rdd @row-with-index)
                        (f/filter #(= row (get % 0))))]
    (when-not (some #(= (get row-and-index 1) %) rows-list) row)))` and I'm running into some kind of error. What am I doing wrong

Comment: Could you post it as a question with example input/output? I am not sure if I understand what your want here (simple filter on row numbers?) on comments are not very well suited for posting code.